# Kafka Connect flatten transformation of a postgres record with array field

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have a postgres DB connected to Kafka using Kafka Connect, in order to put CDC events on a topic.
We use a flatten transformation as part of a shared config:

```
flattenKey:  "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten$Key"
```

One of the columns in the table is of type **ARRAY** and thus when trying to apply the transformation I get an exception:

```
Flatten transformation does not support ARRAY for record without schemas (for field after.role_ids).
```

Kafka connect reference: https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/Flatten.java#L246

I understand that arrays can't be flattened and why, my question is - is there any way I can somehow keep the flatten of the record, but cast / transform the array in some manner so I can still use it?

the array will contain integers, so transforming it into a string where all the elements are separated by commas for example do the trick for me.
Any other suggestion will be great.

We use Debezium for the configuration.

Comment: How does your payload look like?

Comment: Can you link as to why arrays cannot be flattened?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to write your own code to deal with this, either as a [custom Single Message Transform](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/Transformation.html), or a stream processor in something like Kafka Streams.

You could also comment/upvote on [this issue](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/Transformation.html) to add support for a function that would help with this into ksqlDB.

Comment: Any update for this use case? is there any workaround or function which can handle arrays of struct?

Comment: @repcak it's been three years :) you're probably best off opening a new question

Comment: I've aleready opened : )  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76584938/how-to-handle-nested-arrays-of-struct-in-kafka-jdbc-sink-connector/76592064#76592064I was counting on your answer, because I got most of the information about kafka connect and jdbc connector from your tutorials - they are really great .

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Debezium 1.1 or later, I'd suggest to implement a [custom column converter](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/development/converters.html) instead of an SMT. Converters let you adjust schema and value right within Debezium itself, so "transforming it into a string where all the elements are separated by commas" will be done with just a little bit of coding.

Answer (score 1):

In the JDBC sink connector, the Array primitives are handled via the ticket https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/pull/805