# How to handle nested arrays of struct in Kafka JDBC Sink Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk, aws-msk-connect

I'm trying to handle nested arrays of struct via my Kafka Connect JDBC Sink Connector while writing records to Postgres.

Im using Kafka Connect (MSK Connect) build in AWS MSK. (I cannot use KSQL or Kafka Streams right now, or can i? run kafka streams on https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/power-your-kafka-streams-application-with-amazon-msk-and-aws-fargate/)

My schema looks like follows:

```
{
"schema": {
    "type": "struct",
    "fields": [
        {
            "type": "struct",
            "optional": "false",
            "field": "x",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "type": "string",
                    "optional": "true",
                    "field": "y"
                },
                {
                    "type": "string",
                    "optional": "true",
                    "field": "z"
                },
                {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "struct",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "type": "int32",
                                "optional": true,
                                "field": "list-id"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "string",
                                "optional": true,
                                "field": "list-no"
                            }
                        ],
                        "optional": true
                    },
                    "optional": "true",
                    "field": "mylist"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "optional": "true",
    "name": "Name"
},
"payload": {
    "x": {
        "y": "abc",
        "z": "abc",
        "mylist": [
            {
                "list-id": 5080866,
                "list-no": "1"
            },
            {
                "list-id": 3111,
                "list-no": "5"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

And my kafka connect config looks like:

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://HOST:5432/database
topics=testTopic
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
connection.user=user
connection.password=password
auto.create=true
auto.evolve=true
insert.mode=insert
batch.size=200
tasks.max=1
table.name.format=test
transforms=flatten
transforms.flatten.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten$Value
```

I've got an error:

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Flatten transformation does not support ARRAY for record with schemas (for field Name.x.mylist)

Is there a way to deal with this using Kafka Connect?

Comment: Should i create own custom SMT? ( https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/custom.html ) Is this the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should i create own custom SMT? Is this the only way?

Ultimately, yes, that is "one" way, but not very flexible, as SMT require a specific data format.

You could also use Kafka Streams (in ECS/Fargate, yes), Spark, Flink (in EMR), etc to "massage" your data *before* using Kafka Connect (or Spark/Flink can also write to JDBC databases).

Comment: Could you please elaborate "SMT require a specific data format"? Every time the structure is changed will I have to change the SMT? Will I have to write a different SMT for each list of structures in my message?    Do you perhaps know if JDBC connector will work with array of dicts - does this solution also require writing SMT?

Comment: Last I checked, JDBC Sink does not support any type of array. But if you look at Javadoc of Connect Struct/Schema classes, you'll see what I mean about the format. Some SMT change the record format, others don't